# android how to make gridview item corner round

Tags: android, gridview, rounding

I will add a image to show it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dRDlHZAgYbVG5Ca1l2MTZseHc/edit?usp=sharing
you can see the detail in the image.

Comment: you may see more clear from those images:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dRDlHZAgYbSmc4alVOLXRoNG8/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dRDlHZAgYbTENHNXlsRzlCZ2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I set the round background in gridview, but the item is not round, so can't implement it.

Comment: The app in the image you linked to most likely just used png images with rounded corners - nothing special has to be done, just make sure the images in your gridview are already have rounded corners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each grid item use the background below :-
(save the below code in drawable folder)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="@color/black_transparent"/>
         <corners android:bottomRightRadius="12dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"    android:topLeftRadius="12dp" android:topRightRadius="12dp"/>
         </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I solved it, thank you.  I need to set four selector, each selector has only one round corner,  because  the left three corner  is  not  round.  thank you!

Comment: @AndroidStudentM you can look at this demo , https://github.com/com314159/listviewRoundCorner  this is listview, gridview is almost the same.  you should set selector based on the item position.

Answer (score 0):

make grid_item_corner.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set grid **single layout** item

```
  android:background="@drawable/grid_item_corner"
```

I hope this will help you.

Note: Above background property is about grid view single item layout, not to gridview.