# How to implement rounded corners in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

So I find this [android how to make gridview item corner round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916361/android-how-to-make-gridview-item-corner-round). But I dont know how implemet this code to single item in gridview in GridViewAdapter. Could anyone at least show the way where to use it. I try like this
      networkImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.grid_backgroud);
but it doesn't work .

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> images){
        //Getting all the values
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
    }
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Creating a linear layout
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //NetworkImageView
        NetworkImageView networkImageView = new NetworkImageView(context);

        //Initializing ImageLoader
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(images.get(position), ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkImageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Setting the image url to load
        networkImageView.setImageUrl(images.get(position),imageLoader);


        //Scaling the imageview
        networkImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        int width = (display.getWidth()/2)-6;

        networkImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int)width,640));

        //Adding views to the layout
        linearLayout.addView(networkImageView);

        //Returnint the layout
        return linearLayout;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it as the background for your LinearLayout:

```
linearLayout.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever_you_named_the_file, null);
```

## EDIT

Instead of a LinearLayout, use a CardView. It automatically gives you rounded corners.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I still have sharp corners in every item.

Comment: ok i do this and its work but not very well. When I scroll gridview the corners change from from sharp to rounded and conversely. I do this like that

Comment: @PapaSmerf test on another device.

Comment: ok, it works on my pixel 2xl but not on huawei p9. but thanks a lot for help